# Vector Statistical Library - Math Kernel Library

Tags: linker, fortran

Could anyone explain me (in plain English) how to link the Vector Statistical Library (included in the Math Kernel Library) to a Fortran 90 source code compiling with Intel Fortran compiler for Linux?

My makefile looks as follows:

```
f90comp = ifort
libdir = /home/project/
mklpath = /opt/intel/mkl/10.0.5.025/lib/32/
mklinclude = /opt/intel/mkl/10.0.5.025/include/

exec: AAA.o
  $(f90comp) -o AAA -L$(mklpath) -I$(mklinclude) AAA.o -libmkl_ia32.a -lguide -lpthread

AAA.o: $(libdir)AAA.f90
  $(f90comp) -c -L$(mklpath) -I$(mklinclude) $(libdir)AAA.f90 -libmkl_ia32.a -lguide -lpthread
```

It produces the following error:

```
ld: cannot find -libmkl_ia32.a
make: *** Error 1
```

However, the file exists in the specified directory (mklpath).

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you seeing an error message from ifort?  It could be useful to post that to help diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the file really called? -l to the linker is not meant to take a real file name. It is meant to take [x], while the file to be found then is called lib[x].{so,a}.

If you want to give the real object file name, you may either just append it without using -l and using the absolute path, or use -l:[filename].

I assume the right way to do it for you is `-lmkl_ia32` however. Raw filenames are only useful if the lib is not called lib[x].{so,a}